# CSS Flexbox: Always keep items to the right even when wrapped

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to build an interface in which there is a `<select>` element with a `<label>` (grouped in a form group) and a `<button>` next to them. This block should always appear at the right side of the screen. If there is enough horizontal space, all items should stay on 1 line. If the screen is too narrow, the `<select>` should wrap under the `<label>`.

Here is an illustration of what I am trying to achieve:
[image: demonstration of desired UI layout]

Looks straightforward, but I cannot figure out the correct CSS rules. Here are the basic HTML and CSS for this block:

```css
.wide {
  width: 400px;
}
.narrow {
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: 150px;
}
.wide, .narrow {
  border: dotted 1px purple;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.form-group {
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: rgba(255, 235, 60, 0.15);
  /* flex-basis: min-content; */
}
.control-label, .form-control {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
.control-label {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.form-control, button {
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wide">
  <form class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Language selector:</label>
      <select class="form-control">
        <option>Language name</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="button-container">
      <button type="submit">&gt;&gt;</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<br>
<div class="narrow">
  <form class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Language selector:</label>
      <select class="form-control">
        <option>Language name</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="button-container">
      <button type="submit">&gt;&gt;</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

If you run the snippet you will notice that for the narrow container, the form group occupies the whole available horizontal space, which is not what I want. If I add `flex-basis: min-content` to it, then it stays wrapped also in the wide container, which is also not what I want. I am open to solutions which don’t involve flexbox (but not to html tables).

Comment: text-align: right to form-group

Comment: @TemaniAfif that makes the label align with the right side of the select, instead of the left as desired.